# Shortest Algorithm to flip 2 edges on a Rubik's cube

Tags: optimization, rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles, mechanical-puzzles

I'm looking for the shortest algorithm to flip 2 edges without rearranging any other pieces location or orientation. For example, flipping the Top-Front edge and the Top-Right edge. My current best is 12 turns, but would like to learn better if someone can share it.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, my 12 move solution is:

R’ E’ R2 E2 R’ U’ R E2 R2 E R U

(I generally use my own notation, so hopefully I converted it to standard notation correctly.)

Answer (score 3):

Optimal if you allow slice-moves is 11:
M U' M U2 F2 M' U' M' U F2 U'
If you do not, it is 13:
F U2 F2 D' U' L' U L D F2 U' F' U
These results are from cube explorer (http://kociemba.org/download.htm).
It is important to note that not all 2-edge flips are the same. The 11-mover flips to edges that are not near each other. For adjacent edges the optimal 2-flip is indeed 12.